# understanding foreach loop[ with if condition

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement, foreach

```
<?php foreach($get_break as $break ) : ?>
   <?php if($current_time >= $break['break_start'] &&  $current_time <= $break['break_end']) {  ?>
   <ul class="simple-user-list">
    <li>
        <figure class="image rounded">
            <img src="assets/images/!sample-user.jpg" alt="Joseph Doe Junior" class="img-circle">
        </figure>
        <span class="title">i'm still exists</span>
        <span class="message truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</span>
    </li>
</ul>
<?php } elseif($break['break_type'] == "Additional break") { ?>
<ul class="simple-user-list">
    <li>
        <figure class="image rounded">
            <img src="assets/images/!sample-user.jpg" alt="Joseph Doe Junior" class="img-circle">
        </figure>
        <span class="title">i'm not exists</span>
        <span class="message truncate">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</span>
    </li>
</ul>
<?php } ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

I want to display the break based on the time.
I have break master table containing various break type with break start time and break end time.
based on the current time, I want to display the breaks.
Here I;m using foreach for getting data from break table
and checking the condition using if. check break with the current time.
for the current time, specific break should be displayed.
problem is, here if the condition is displaying the current, where in the else part , even if the if condition is true it display's the additional break.
what should I need to do? to display the only break, if no current break exists for the current time. it displays the additional break.

Comment: Can you post the values you are getting in your `foreach` for  `$break['break_start']`, `$break['break_end']` and `$current_time`?

Comment: whats is value of $current_time ?

Comment: @BrijalSavaliya getting the current  date

Comment: what is a break type?

Comment: @Progrock  break type is lunch break, tea break ect. with break start time and break end time

Comment: If there is no break currently, then what do you want to display?  The next break?   What is an additional break?

Comment: if no break i want to display the additional break

Answer (score 1):

You can not do math with date strings. use the `strtotime()` function to do math with dates.

read more about it [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

So you get something like this:

```
if(strtotime($current_time) >= strtotime($break['break_start']) &&  strtotime($current_time) <= strtotime($break['break_end'])) {
    //dothis
}
```

> strtotime — Parse about any English textual datetime description into a Unix timestamp

So if your date is not set up like the english way (11/12/2016) use `date()` to transform it into a good date string.